# WPF - using video as background

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering if it's possible to use a video as a background in WPF? What I mean with this is that I want to have a video playing in the background with my controls on top of it. If you still don't quite understand me you should take a look at this site: http://www.barrelny.com/recap/2012/. Is this possible to achive in WPF? if so, how do I do this?

Comment: You could also achieve the result by placing the controls on top of a mediaelement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  VisualBrush for more information visit the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189009(v=vs.95).aspx) link

For example in following code snippet I am using video background in button

```
<Button.Background>
    <VisualBrush>
      <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <StackPanel Background="White">
          <Image Source="MyFile.wmv" Opacity="0.3"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
      </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
 </Button.Background>
```

Comment: How to create Image with source from MKV programatically?