# using video as background of a grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, video

I want to display a video as background of a grid. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36629246/519413) I created this grid code:

```html
<Grid>
  <Grid.Background>
    <VisualBrush>
      <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <StackPanel Background="White">
          <Image Source="/WPF.Resources;component/Videos/background.wmv" Opacity="0.3"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
      </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
  </Grid.Background>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="491" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="491" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="250" />
    <RowDefinition Height="250" />
    <RowDefinition Height="105" />
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

However I am getting this error:

> Blend does not support this file format. D:\WPF\Resources\Videos\background.wmv

What type of file WPF support as video background? I tried to play the video and I can play it so it is a valid file format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Image` use `MediaElement`.

```
<VisualBrush.Visual>            
       <StackPanel Background="White">
                        <MediaElement Source="/WPF.Resources;component/Videos/background.wmv" Opacity="0.3"></MediaElement>
                    </StackPanel>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
```

Go to Properties of the ***background.wmv*** file and in `Copy to Output Directory` select `Copy always`. This means that the video will be copied to bin folder and from there wpf application will be able to access the file and it will be dispayed.

[image]

Comment: If you also need to make it loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406736/what-is-simplest-way-to-repeat-a-video-in-a-mediaelement

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MediaElement` instead of `Image`.

Comment: The error is gone, but when I run the application, it doesn't show the video.